# iPhone 4s and iCloud only partially syncing

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, iphone, contacts

I'm having trouble syncing -- my iCloud and iPhone 4s (running iOS 5.1.1) only partially sync with one another. I.e., new entries sync, as do changes to contacts that appear in both. BUT… I have numerous entries on my phone that have never copied over. Moreover, even when I deleted all my contacts on my iPhone, my favorites still had names, as did my texts. I mention in case this is related. Did I fail to truly wipe contacts from my phone?
I tried [tubedogg's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/54484/tubedogg) advice in [iPhone contacts aren't syncing to iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100659/iphone-contacts-arent-syncing-to-icloud) to turn off iCloud, wait 15min, and then turn it on again and it increased the number of my contacts dramatically, from about 3600 to about 5600. 
FYI, in iTunes, I've checked the option for Auto backup via iCloud.
I'll happily rewrite this question -- and/or welcome edits. I'm new to the community and appreciate help (& apologies for being longwinded).